# ajax inserting $(data) before an element

Tags: ajax

Is there a way to insert the data selector from an ajax function return before an element? Like

```
$(data).insertBefore("#placeholder");
```

Or do I need to use an append function? I need to put the data on my console without deleting the elements already there, the .html() function I am using removed my div tag for placeholding.

Comment: You need to show what `data` is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is text,

```
   var dataelem=$('<div>'+data+'</div>');
   $('#placeholder').prepend(dataelem);
```

This will place data infront of #placeholder.